# Whats encryption is use there

Tags: encryption

Please help me and give me this decrypted, or tell me what sort of encryption or hash is used here.

```
aHR0cHM6Ly9tZWdhLm56LyMhZmt3UTJESlQhd21qYkNDZXZHbDNrS1ZqWGRGWnpmRDBwbjlyb2tWNUdf​YmxwQzlUbTRVUQ==
```

Comment: Any efforts from your side ?

Comment: None, that's an encoding.

Answer (score 4):

I presume you are joking. If you place it into a base64 decoder, you get https://mega.nz and some additional characters.